# Does pfSense in access point mode support WPS clients?

Tags: wireless-networking, pfsense

**TL;DR: I would like to connect a wifi client which supports only WPS to a pfSense running in access point mode. Is that possible, and how?**

I am in the process of replacing my ISP provided router with pfSense. I got everything to work, including Internet routing and IPTV.

One of my IPTV receivers is in a room with no LAN wiring. This has been solved by a pair of wifi bridges (Arris VAP2400/VAP2404, [instructions here](http://www.ovislink.ca/Products%20imgs/motorola/VAP2400/Motorola%20VAP%202400%20User%20584371-001-5.pdf)), one connected to the router, the other to the IPTV device.

These devices essentially act as a pair of wifi access point and client. Out of the box, each device is an access point; it can be turned into a client by connecting to another access point via WPS. (They have an IP address, which indicates there may be some kind of web configurator with additional options, but I am specifically interested in the WPS part.)

Since the pfSense runs on an ALIX single-board computer with built-in wifi, I am wondering if I can ditch the upstream WAP2400 and connect the downstream one directly to the pfSense as a client. (This may require the wifi interface to have the correct LAN configuration for IPTV, which is beyond the scope of this question – I am only interested in getting the wifi association to work.) However, I did not find any WPS-related settings in the pfSense GUI.

Does pfSense support WPS clients at all? If so, what are the steps to associate a WPS client? (The device does not have a hardware WPS button, so this functionality would have to be available in software.)

Comment: [Yes](https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/monitoring/status/wireless.html) it does appear that pfSense supports WPS.  You are aware that WPS is extremely insecure, right?

Comment: I am aware of some security issues with WPS, but as I understand, each of them requires the attacker to be able to press the button on the access point (or trigger the software equivalent thereof) – if I am wrong, pointers would be appreciated. Also, this seems to be a switched network shared by all IPTV servers and STBs of my ISP, and separated from my Internet access. Therefore, in this use case WPS is not the weakest link, nor does that network have any resources of particular interest.

Comment: WPS along with WPA can be brute forced within minutes.  At this point only WPA2 and WPA3 is secure with WPA3 being the suggested solution.  WPA2 has not weaknesses except brute force.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching the pfSense documentation for WPS found only one match, in the [wireless scan results](https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/monitoring/status/wireless.html). That indicates pfSense has no support for WPS – not surprising, given that several other OSes have withdrawn WPS support over security concerns.

Another pitfall would be frequency. My pfSense runs on hardware I bought back in 2014, with a 2.4 GHz-only wifi adapter. The VAP240x, on the other hand, is a 5 GHz-only device – being only designed for bridging between two identical devices, compatibility with older devices is not an issue, and exclusively using a newer (and likely less congested) frequency band may even be a bonus. In my case, however, that means my VAP240x will never be able to associate with my pfSense with the hardware in place at the moment.